# jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0 - How can I submit by link click rather than submit button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using some of the default Validation on my form. For example when you click the Submit button the form validates. What I would like to do is click a link and then the form will validate. How do I setup something like that?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129029/jquery-validation-onclick) other question may help you

Comment: When posting questions on SO, just pretend like we can't see any of your code, then post the relevant parts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can add a click event to your link and call form.validate for example.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a guess based on the limited information, but the jquery-validate plugin will handle intercepting submit events.

```
$("form.formToValidate").validate({
  ... validate options here
});

$("a.linkToClick").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("form.formToValidate").submit();
});
```