# jQuery Form Validator validate on button click

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jQuery Form Validator](http://formvalidator.net/)  and I need to validate the form on button (not submit) click. Cannot figure out how to do it.

I have set it up with custom error messages :

```
$.validate({
    language: myLanguage
});
```

Comment: Perhaps related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129029/jquery-validation-onclick

Comment: That's a different library.

Comment: Indeed it is, though the solution could have still been helpful. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried finding the solution in their documentation. I guess I have to switch to more popular validation library you referred to.

Answer (score 1):

> http://formvalidator.net/#configuration_callbacks

You can use it like that:

```
$.validate({
form : '#registration-form',
modules : 'security',
onError : function() {
  alert('Validation failed');
},
onSuccess : function() {
  alert('The form is valid!');
  return false; // Will stop the submission of the form
},
onValidate : function() {
  return {
    element : $('#some-input'),
    message : 'This input has an invalid value for some reason'
  }
}
});
```

Or use an event listeners:

```
$('input')
.bind('beforeValidation', function() {
  console.log('Input "'+this.name+'" is about to become validated');
})
.bind('validation', function(evt, isValid) {
  console.log('Input "'+this.name+'" is ' + (isValid ? 'VALID' : 'NOT VALID'));
});
```

Comment: I tried to find the diffrent ways of manual validation. But i got to the point, that i can't get config from the plugin.